# SQlite syntax error, cant find it

Tags: sqlite

Sorry for the noob question, I'm used to MySQL.

This SQlite query apparently has some syntax error, but I can't find it - do you see it?

```
CREATE TABLE `dash_viewports_dvi` (
`id_dvi` integer unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
  `panel_count_dvi` integer unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 5,
  `panel_size_dvi` integer unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 6,
  `name_dvi` text NOT NULL
);
```

It's sqlite v. 3.7.13.

Comment: if you get a syntax error message, tell us what it is...

Comment: If I knew that, I wouldn't ask here. phpliteadmin just says it's wrong, no details :(

Comment: nop, even if I drop the `NOT NULL` completely it is still complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is "near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error".

Autoincrementing fields must be signed:

```
id_dvi INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
```

Comment: Oh, that is really odd. They also have to be nullable... Any idea why this restriction is there? It makes no sense to me - negative indexes? Null indexes?

Comment: `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is implicitly NOT NULL, because NULL values are converted to an integer key. Also, SQLite doesn't support the standard definition of autoincrement. See http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Interesting, seems my idea that Sqlite is "mysql in a file" was far from truth...

Comment: @MightyPork Then I'd also strongly suggest you read about its (lack of) [data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: Yeah I've noticed how everything seems to be text